# React.js moving on to the next list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a movie search page. When I search something, it goes through the data base and find the very first match and display on the page. However, I want to create a function, so when I click next, page displays next movie in the data base. My code follows:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import SearchBar from './Bar/index.js';
import SearchResult from './Result/index.js';
import axios from 'axios';

import './index.css';

class SearchArea extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchText: '',
            searchResult: {},
            result: false,
            count: 0
        };
    }

    handleSearchBarChange(event) {
        this.setState({searchText: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSearchBarSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const movie = this.state.searchText;
        axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=c6cd73ec4677bc1d7b6560505cf4f453&language=en-US&query=${movie}&page=1&include_adult=false`)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.data.results.length >= 0) {
                const i = 0;
                const {
                    title,
                    overview,
                    release_date: releaseDate
                } = response.data.results[this.state.count];

                const posterPath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154' + response.data.results[this.state.count].poster_path;

                this.setState({
                    searchResult: {
                        title,
                        posterPath,
                        overview,
                        releaseDate
                    },
                    result: true
                });
            }
            else {
                this.setState({
                    searchResult: {
                        title: 'No Result',
                        overview: 'No Overview Available',
                        posterPath: ''
                    },
                    result: true
                });
            }
        })
    }

    handleSearchNext(event) {
        this.handelSearchBarSubmit.overview = response.data.results[1];
    }

    handleResultClose() {
        this.setState({
            searchResult: {},
            result: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar 
                value = {this.state.searchText}
                onChange = {this.handleSearchBarChange.bind(this)}
                onSubmit = {this.handleSearchBarSubmit.bind(this)}
                onNext = {this.handleSearchNext.bind(this)}
                />
                {this.state.result && 
                <SearchResult
                 searchResult = {this.state.searchResult}
                 onClose = {this.handleResultClose.bind(this)}
                 onAdd = {this.props.onAdd}
                />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SearchArea.propTypes = {
    onAdd: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default SearchArea;
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make handleSearchNext. Please help

**EDIT**
Following is the SearchBar code

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import styles from './index.css';

const SearchBar = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={(event) => props.onSubmit(event)}>
                <input
                    className="searchBar"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search Here"
                    value={props.value}this
                    onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event)}
                    onNext={(event) => props.onChange(event)}
                    onBack={(event) => props.onChange(event)}
                />
                <Button className="button" type="submit">Sumbit</Button>
            </form>
            <Button className={styles.button} type="previous">Back</Button>
            <Button className="button" type="next">Next</Button>
        </div>
    );
};

SearchBar.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onBack: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onNext: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: But it looks like you are already querying for a full page of movies, do you want the next page or the next movie here?

Comment: If your specific question is "Why doesn't `handleSearchNext` execute?" we'd need to see the code for your `<SearchBar>` component.

Comment: What is `this.state.count` counting?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your server respond with not only the requested title, but also the next one. That way, when you click on Next, you can immediately display the next movie without waiting for a response, while still querying it in the background by name or id (so that you have the next after it, etc.).

**Edit**: If I misunderstood what you meant and you already have this (it looks like you are actually querying a whole page of movies at once), you probably simply want something like

```
handleSearchNext(event) {
    this.setState({ searchResult: response.data.results[1], result: true });
}
```

and handle specially the case when you hit the last item on the page.

Comment: Right now, when I search for a movie, only one movie appears on the search result. I tried using array with response.data.results, but was not successful in loading multiple results at once. So, I wanted to use setState to load with i increment everytime I press next button.

Comment: If you don't have the data then you need to query it first like you did with `axios.get(...` the first time.